# Angularjs : How to display float number to nearst rounded number

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs variable bill_amount which store 500.44. How can I display it to 501 without using controller function. 
I use`{{bill_amount | number: 0}}` but it show 500 when the amount is greater than .5 then it adds +1 on the amount but I need to add +1  on the amount if the amount is greater then .0 like if the amount is 500.1 than I want to show 501.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Math.ceil()
```

Example `Math.ceil(1.4)` results '2'

Comment: In template view, this function does not display any value. when i display like this <p>{{ Math.ceil(bill_amount) }}</p>

Comment: In view Math.ceil() not work. use this function before the value that return from controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter to round numbers up:

```
angular.module('app').filter('numberCeil', function(){
    return function(value){
        return Math.ceil(value);
    };
});
```

Then use it like a regular filter:

```
{{ bill_amount | numberCeil }}
```

Comment: Thanx for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use bill_amount = Math.ceil(1.4) in your controller and then use {{bill_amount}} in your view.

Comment: Sir i can't do this on controller, if i do this on controller than i got some logical mistake in my program.

Comment: Ideal place for your business logic is Controller. I dounbt existence of any scenario where you will get logical error when you write something in controller.

Comment: Thanx sir, I got answer to custom filter

Answer (score 0):

add filter in your app

```
 app.filter("numberExchange", [
      function () {
          return function(item) {
              return Math.ceil(item);
          }
      }


    ]);
```

and then use it on your view :
{{bill_amount | numberExchange}}